# re-render select options

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I have this following ko template

```
<select name="payment[fabinst_tenor]"
                        class="select select-tenor"
                        data-bind="
                attr: {id: getCode() + '_tenor', name: 'payment[' + getTransportName() + ']',
                'data-validate': JSON.stringify({required:true})},
                options: getTenors(),
                optionsValue: 'term',
                optionsText: 'text',
                optionsCaption: '',
                optionsAfterRender: optionsAfterRender,
                value: selectedTenorTerm">
                </select>
```

and the related JS code is

```
            optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) {
            if(typeof item !== 'undefined') {
                if('disabled' in item && item.disabled) { // default output from PHP
                    option.disabled = true;
                    option.text = option.text + ' (' + $t('Minimum payment is') + ' ' + utils.formatPrice(item.min_total,window.checkoutConfig.priceFormat ) + ')';
                } else {
                    var monthlyPrice = quote.totals()['base_grand_total'] / item.term;
                    option.text = option.text + ' x ' + utils.formatPrice(monthlyPrice,window.checkoutConfig.priceFormat );
                }
            }
        },
```

How to re-render the options when quote.totals() is changed upon an ajax call?

Comment: maybe i should move the logic to getTenors instead

Comment: nope. moving to getTenors doesn't update the options disability status when quote.totals() is changed